# Spinner onItemReselected() event android

Tags: android, android-spinner

Is there a way to get notified if an item was re-selected by user in a [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)? [`AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) only has two methods `onItemSelected()` and  `onNothingSelected()`. I was wondering if there is something similar to `onItemReselected()`.

Please note that `onItemSelected()` is not invoked for already selected position otherwise it would have been just a matter of keeping old selection and comparing them.

Comment: Why not keep an array of booleans to check re-selection?

Comment: What exactly your requirements are?

Comment: @Gunaseelan Well default behavior wont hide spinner drop down, I want to hide it manually. Or may be I want to do something with the row that was re-selected, play denial animation (shake) on it etc.

Comment: Okay friend! Got it.. But I think there is no default way. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to keep a nice `boolean[]` where every `boolean` represents one item, storing wether that item has been selected.